# Firebase authentication trigger when email has been verified

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

We have an app where the user initially uses Firebase anon-authentication. If the user later authenticates in the app using email method, we want to modify the users profile data with information that he is really authenticated. In the below documentation it is stated that **user.create** is triggered when "A user creates an email account and password.". However, it is not clear if the trigger is run AFTER the email has been verified, or before. This is important. We want to only handle the case when the email account is created AND verified. Is this possible to detect? Or is there some other trigger for when the email has been verified?

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/firebase-auth

Comment: Email verification is not part of the event trigger.  You will have to write more code to do something after the email is verified, but it won't be an auth trigger.  The dup shows an example of writing a second http function that the client can call after verification occurs.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the hint. This is what I felt when reading the documentation. What I will do is that I will run a cloud function to perform the update of the user profile data when I know in the client that the user has validated its email.